# MongoDB Query in Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a collection in this format:

```
{
"name": ....,
"users": [....,....,....,....]
}
```

I have two different names and I want to find the total number of users that belongs to both documents. Now, I am doing it with Python. I download the document of name 1 and the document of name 2 and check how many users are in both of the documents. I was wondering if there is any other way to do it only with MongoDB and return the number.

Example:

```
{
"name": "John",
"users": ["001","003","008","010"]
}

{
"name": "Peter",
"users": ["002, "003", "004","005","006","008"]
}
```

The result would be `2` since users 003 and 008 belongs to both documents.

How I do it:

```
doc1 = db.collection.find_one({"name":"John"})
doc2 = db.collection.find_one({"name":"Peter"})

total = 0
for user in doc1["users"]:
    if user in doc2["users"]:
       total += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do this with the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/), but I think it would only make sense if you were doing this over a more than two users even though your could use it that way:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
         "name": { "$in": [ "John", "Peter" ] }
    }},

    { "$unwind": "$users" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$users",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$match": { "count": { "$gt": 1 } }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

That allows you to find the same counts over the names you supply to [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) in [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)

Comment: I don't have the option to change the scheme of the database. This is a procedure I will have to run only once in a while and will do in every combination of names.

Comment: @Sfinos I think you misread as well as I did myself and you have caught me in between edits. This is using the aggregate method to match up the entries across users.

Comment: You are right. My comment was for your previous answer (userCount). Since I am not familiar with aggregate, do you know which one is faster? Python or MongoDB solution?

Comment: @Sfinos In all likelihood the aggregate method should be faster, if not only for you are not fetching both records. It also easily expands if you want to do this other more than two users, just supply more it `$in`. In this case, as with your `.findOne` queries the important thing is to index the "name" field. There are some links in the answer to documentation. Pymongo syntax does not vary much from as shown